# How to pass a multiline directive to apache using the -c parameter?

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to start apache from the command line, passing it a directive using the "-c" parameter :

```
sudo httpd -c "<VirtualHost *:80>\n</VirtualHost>"
```

But it fails :

```
httpd: Syntax error in -C/-c directive: -c/-C directives:1: <VirtualHost> was not closed.
```

I also tried passing a multiline string using PHP through exec/system, but it fails too :

```
<?php

$directive = <<<EOT
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
EOT;

exec("sudo httpd -c \"" . $directive . "\"");
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible !

-c / -C will act as one line in httpd.conf, so you can add as many parameters as lines :

```
sudo httpd -c "<VirtualHost *:80>" -c "</VirtualHost>"
```